# Convert json data in cp1251 encoding

Tags: json, perl

I work with data from web forms in cp1251;
I need to convert hash with data to JSON

When i used

```
my $href = {a => "дот"};
my $str = to_json($href, {utf8 => 0});

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($str); # will print something like this {"a": "\x{c4}\x{ee}\x{e8}"}
```

i need to make JSON string without converting.

In this case helps something like this:

```
my $str = encode('cp1251', decode('cp1251', to_json($href, {utf8 => 0}) ));
print Dumper($str); # will print {"a": "дот"}
```

or

```
my $str = to_json($href, {utf8 => 0});
utf8::downgrade($str);
print Dumper($str); # will print {"a": "дот"}
```

What other right options are there to solve the problem?

Comment: What is your OS? If OS is MS Windows what command `chcp` (code page) returns?

Comment: Your first snippet shows the expected output. It shows that `$str` contains `{ "a": "дот" }` encoded using cp1251

Comment: Isn't JSON required to use utf-8?

Comment: @Shawn, Originally, no. If you follow the RFC, yes, unless it's part of a "closed ecosystem". Since this appear to be part of a private API (front end and back end of an app talking to each other), using an encoding other than UTF-8 would be allowed even according to the RFC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the encode_json function from the JSON module to generate a JSON string from a data structure in a specified encoding. For example:

```
use JSON qw(encode_json);
my $href = {a => "дот"};
my $str = encode_json($href, {utf8 => 0, encode_check_method => 'sv'});
print Dumper($str); # will print {"a": "дот"}
```

The encode_check_method option specifies the method used to check for characters that cannot be encoded in the specified encoding. The value sv checks the SVf_UTF8 flag on the scalar, which means that it will only encode characters that are not flagged as UTF-8.

Alternatively, you can use the encode function from the Encode module to encode the JSON string after it has been generated:

```
use Encode qw(encode);
my $href = {a => "дот"};
my $json = to_json($href, {utf8 => 0});
my $str = encode('cp1251', $json);
print Dumper($str); # will print {"a": "дот"}
```

This will encode the JSON string in the cp1251 encoding after it has been generated.